# al poner localhost y buscar mi carpeta me muestra xampp completamente en blanco

Tags: php, web, desarrollo

Hay alguna solucin para que xampp me demuestre mi carpeta cuando la mando allamar?
[image: mando allamar la carpeta y me aparecen en blanco]

[image: reviso la mis carpetas y esta todo en orden]

Comment: Indica en el navegador la ruta completa, **yugi/login.php** o en su defecto **index.php**.

Comment: Hola A Francisco Samuel Torres Lope, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, evita usar imágenes, y adjunta el código y los mensajes de error como texto, saludos.

Comment: Veo que tu Index.php esta vacio, estas seguro de que estas desplegando contenido en el?

Comment: Por defecto se esta cargando en pantalla el index y este se ve en 0 kb. Osea, no tiene nada dentro